# Will a Handler's constructor always return before it starts accepting messages?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I create a Handler that processes messages via handleMessage() in my app that needs to trigger other stuff once it's up and running. To accomplish this, I've set it up so it calls this.sendEmptyMessage() on itself in the constructor, which gets things going. This ensures the class is fully initialized before anything else tries to send messages to it. I just need to be *absolutely sure* the constructor will return before the sendEmptyMessage() call is executed because I later access the Handler via the variable returned by the constructor, and sending messages to a null Handler would be a problem.

Here's my code:

```
public myFavoriteHandler(Looper looper) {
    super(looper);
    this.sendEmptyMessage(DO_INITIALIZE); // DO_INITIALIZE is a static final int
}
```

Comment: so how can you call `Handler#sendEmptyMessage` if you dont have a reference to that `Handler` (its constructor has not finished yet)?

Comment: @pskink: Inside of the constructor, `this` is already available (but it may not be fully initialized yet).

Comment: if you called `super` (or the default `super` is used) it is fully initialized already

Comment: @pskink Sorry, I call it using this.sendEmptyMessage(). I'll update the question and add that.

Comment: so after calling `super(looper);` your `Handler` is up and ready and you can start sending `Message`s

Comment: But why don't you just do that initializing part in the constructor as well?

Comment: @Thilo Because I need to make sure the constructor returns and sets its variable before I execute the actual initialization code since it calls other threads that refer to the Handler by the variable.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, but if you put `setMyVariable()` right after `super(looper)`, then there is no way anything can get in between.